# Terrible Java 8 performance when using nested Intstream loops

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

After reading about Java 8's java.util.stream.Intstream, I have been replacing some of the traditional loops with streams. Unfortunately, I ran into some performance issues when dealing with nested loops.

As expected, the following code runs in about 47 ms in my machine:

```
IntStream.range(0, 1000000000).forEach(i -> {});
```

However, nesting another IntStream hyper inflates the execution time to about 10,458 ms - i.e.:

```
IntStream.range(0, 1000000000).forEach(i -> {
    IntStream.range(0, 1).forEach(j -> {});
});
```

Is this a case of misuse on my part, or is this an issue that may be resolved in the future?

**EDIT:** Just for comparison, the following code ran much faster (in 1,801 ms) using a traditional inner loop. So even when taking optimization into account, there seems to be more overhead using an inner IntStream?

```
final long[] random = {1};
IntStream.range(0, 1000000000).forEach(i -> {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        random[0] += i;
    }
});
```

Comment: The loop probably is optimized out in the first example since it doesn't do anything -- benchmarking 101.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that one billion streams come for free ...

Comment: Terrible? 10.5 seconds for 1B iterations is just 10.5 nanoseconds per iteration or only about 20 cycles of a modern CPU. Is it really terrible cost for using Stream API? Try to measure some meaningful job using proper benchmarking tool - and this will probably answer your question.

Comment: In other words, in one case the optimizer figured out that you are actually doing nothing, in the other, it didn’t. Note really relevant to real life code…  By the way, the intended way of doing such an operation would be `IntStream.range(0, 1000000000).flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, 1)).forEach(i -> {});`

Comment: Even if the methods are compared keeping "benchmarking 101" in mind (use the result, warmup etc), there is a noticable difference. That's not sooo suprising, however. The inner loop will be optimized away to a single addition. The inner stream can not be optimized like this. However, the difference starts to vanish as soon as the upper limit of the inner loop/range is increased. For `j<1000` it's in the order of 300 vs. 270ms (still larger than I expected, though...)

Answer (score 8):

It's not the terrible performance in the second case. It's actually the unbelievably great performance in the first case. See, you iterate over one billion of elements, and the iteration takes only 47 ms. Thus in one second you're able to iterate over 1000/47 = 21 billion of elements! The frequency of your CPU is probably about 3 GHz, thus you iterate over 7 elements in single CPU cycle! Such optimization is performed by JIT-compiler for very simple loop (actually it's absolutely optimized out during the dead code elimination). However you won't earn money writing empty loops. If you add at least some of non-trivial logic, some of optimizations will turn off or become much less effective, so you will have a significant performance drop.

I suggest you to perform the testing on the real code and profile your application for the slowest parts. Artificial examples have nothing in common with the real performance of production code.

Comment: I don’t think that the loop is unrolled and vectorized in this special case. It’s simply removed completely after a certain warm-up phase…

Comment: @Holger, seems you're right, thanks. After warm-up my benchmark shows constant execution time 20us for different range size. Seems that OP's time measurement was performed for cold code.

Answer (score 3):

From the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#forEach-java.util.function.IntConsumer-):

> void forEach(IntConsumer action)
>       Performs an action for each element of this stream.
>       This is a terminal operation.
>
> Terminal operations, such as Stream.forEach or IntStream.sum, may
>   traverse the stream to produce a result or a side-effect. After the
>   terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is considered
>   consumed, and can no longer be used; if you need to traverse the same
>   data source again, you must return to the data source to get a new
>   stream. In almost all cases, terminal operations are eager, completing
>   their traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline
>   before returning. Only the terminal operations iterator() and
>   spliterator() are not; these are provided as an "escape hatch" to
>   enable arbitrary client-controlled pipeline traversals in the event
>   that the existing operations are not sufficient to the task.

There is an overhead of creating lots of Streams. Have you tried to run the code with profiler?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did suspect that there would be an overhead associated with creating Streams, but I did not know how much of an effect that it would have. So perhaps there is no straightforward way of converting nested for loops into one using streams?